# How to connect QLineEdit focusOutEvent

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlineedit

I have designed a window with a `QLineEdit` in PyQt4 with the help of Designer. I converted `.ui` to `.py` using `pyuic4`. I created another `.py` file and imported and subclassed `Ui_Class`.

I want to perform some task when `QLineEdit` lost focus.

Just line button clicked event i to connect `QLineEdit` Lost focus event

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an `eventFilter`:

```
class Filter(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        # FocusOut event
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            # do custom stuff
            print 'focus out'
            # return False so that the widget will also handle the event
            # otherwise it won't focus out
            return False
        else:
            # we don't care about other events
            return False
```

And in your window:

```
# ...
self._filter = Filter()
# adjust for your QLineEdit
self.ui.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self._filter)
```